# Enum pointers in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Enum:

```
    enum DataStatus
    {
        DataNotAvailable = -1,
        DataLocallyAvailable = 0,
        DataExternallyAvailable = 1,
    };
```

Function definition:

```
    GetDataStatusByFrame(UINT PI_uiRequestFrameNo, DataStatus *PO_peDataStatus);
```

Comparsion:

```
    IDataHandler::DataStatus* pinnedPointer = new IDataHandler::DataStatus();
    GetDataStatusByFrame(1, pinnedPointer);

    if (pinnedPointer == IDataHandler::DataStatus::DataNotAvailable) // 'cannot convert' exception
    {
      // ...
    }
```

Question:

**How can i compare these types or at least cast them to the same datatype?**

Comment: Can you not just dereference the pointer?

Comment: Maybe you could do with some *back to basics* information. Consider reading about pointers in your favorite book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API looks like it is intended to be called in a slightly simpler manner to avoid dynamically allocating memory that you need to clean up later. Just put the variable on the stack and it will be cleaned up automatically;

```
IDataHandler::DataStatus status;

GetDataStatusByFrame(1, &status);

if (status == IDataHandler::DataStatus::DataNotAvailable) // 'cannot convert' exception
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if (*pinnedPointer == IDataHandler::DataStatus::DataNotAvailable)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (*pinnedPointer == IDataHandler::DataStatus::DataNotAvailable)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the allocation necessary?  Why not do the following instead?

```
IDataHandler::DataStatus status;
GetDataStatusByFrame(1, &status);
if (status == IDataHandler::DataStatus::DataNotAvailable) {
    // ...
}
```

It is very rare to allocate to an `enum` pointer.  Usually you pass the address of a statically allocated variable.